# What kinds of enchantments can be put onto orbs?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, implements

I've searched everywhere online and can't find the answers I'm looking for about Magic Orbs for my Wizard character for D&D - 4th Ed., so I'll ask them here.

What kinds of enchantments can be put onto orbs? Do they have to be specific to a certain type of spell (Force, Fire or Lightning), or can it be a general +2 to attack rolls (my char is Lv. 6)? Can it be a +2 to Intelligence rolls?

I have the Enchant Magic Item Ritual and I'm trying to learn the specifics on what can be put onto an Orb so I can craft one (or several, if necessary) to aid me in battle. Thanks in advance for any help and answers offered.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Each Item can only have a single enchantment when enchanted manually(PC or NPC). GM crafted enchanted items are at their digression. If you plan on wanting three enchantments you will need three orbs and they wont stack. Your DM however has the power to provide you with a special orb if he/she sees fit.

Answer (score 2):

Generally in 4e the best way to find something is to go to the [compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx). Even if you don't have a DDI subscription you can still use it to search and it has very nice filtering tools.

For instance, open the compendium, type "orb" into the search box, use the dropdown next to "Search" to select "Items" and then in the dropdown next to Category select "Implement"

This gives you a list of every orb enhancement available in the game with the source location. If you have a DDI subscription you can see them all, if not you'll have to go find the book location for the ones that interest you.

Comment: As for the compendium, I'm not a fan of pay-for services. Thanks all the same, though.

Comment: Searching the compendium is free and they provide the book location, though the text is paid. I wish you well trying to play 4e without DDI, I wouldn't even try.

Answer (score 1):

In 4e, there aren't any effects of which you can put multiple instances on an object (i.e., what I understand by your definition of "enchantments"). There's a list of magic items in the PHBs and a couple of splatbooks. When you perform the Enchant Magic Item ritual, that item becomes one of the magic items listed, provided it is your level or lower. If you still want to customize something, though, I'd suggest you speak to your GM about creating a custom magic item.

Comment: But with the DM's permition, I could conceivably create am Magic Orb of Wisdom that gives a +2 to atk rolls?

Comment: @JohnW generally items are not used in 4e to improve your stats, implements of a given enchantment will increase your attack and damage by the plus they have. Do you have access to any source material so you could look at some examples of what exists already?

Comment: I'll have to ask my DM next weekend.